# How to dynamically increase Parallel.ForEach loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I am using below code but run only one loop but it have to go into infinite loop

```
List<string> aa = new List<string>();
aa.Add("aa");                        

Parallel.ForEach(aa, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, bb =>
{                       
    Console.WriteLine("value:" + bb);                                  
    aa.Add("asasasa");               

    Thread.Sleep(10);                           
});
```

Here only one loop of `Parallel.ForEach` run but I have added value in list "aa" so it should go to infinite loop, but it is not behaving like that.

Comment: Normally it's a bad idea to modify a collection which you are enumerating. I don't see why modifying a collection on which you are `Parallel.ForEach` should be a good idea.

Comment: Why are you using `Parallel.ForEach` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`? That doesn't make any sense, since it means the loop won't be actually parallel.

Comment: Even if this *was* working, it wouldn't be an infinite loop, it would be a loop that crashes when aa ends up with so many items in it that you run out of virtual address space.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't really tell your use-case I can only guess. But to me it sounds like you are facing a producer-consumer problem.

Checkout IProducerConsumerCollection and the implementation BlockingCollection. With GetConsumingEnumerable you'll get something that you can use in a foreach, while it gets filled from another place.

hth

Comment: i just want  Parallel.ForEach loop to be infinite as first time list aa has only one value now inside the loop i added one more item to list aa so one more loop to be executed

Answer (score 0):

That's simply not how foreach works. It enumerates a collection, which means it goes through all the items of the collection one by one. In this point of view, using a parallel foreach instead of the serial one doesn't make any difference, the size of the enumerable collection is determined at start of the iteration.

If you want to have an infinite loop, try the

> > while(true) 
> >         { 
> >              aa.Add("asasasa");
> >         }

structure instead.

Comment: my main moto is that suppose MaxDegreeOfParallelism =5 but now only 2 thread is active so i want to add data to my source (list aa)

Comment: I don't really understand what do you want.